# Help with basic Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, invocable-method

Hello trying to branch out of my basic Admin duties to learn a bit more on Apex. I am looking to create an Invocable Apex class that updates a User based on a list of Users being passed to it from a Flow. The flow knows the records to update and what to update about the records. Because of mixed DML I just need Apex to do the actual update outside of the flow for me. I have it as maybe 2 classes to do this but feel like it could be done in one? Just really not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```apex
public class UserIdVariables {
    @InvocableVariable
    public List<User> users;

    @InvocableVariable
    public String newisActive;
}

public class UserIdVariablesClass {
    @InvocableMethod(label = 'Update Records')
    public static void updateUsers(List<UserIdVariables> oldValues){
        List<User> Updatedusers = new List<User>();
        for(UserIdVariables value : oldValues){
            for(User use : value.users){
                use.isActive = value.newIsActive;
                Updatedusers.add(use);
            }
        }
        update Updatedusers;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually do this in the flow, simply by adding a Pause element before updating the users.

However, as far as the actual Apex code goes, you can't mix Setup and non-Setup objects in the same transaction. To solve that problem, just add a Queueable to the mix, and you're good to go:

```
public class UserIdVariablesClass implements Queueable {
    public class UserIdVariables {
        @InvocableVariable public List<User> users;
        @InvocableVariable public String newisActive;
    }
    List<UserIdVariables> values;
    // Constructor to store the values
    public UpdateIdVariablesClass(List<UserIdVariables> oldValues) {
        values = oldValues;
    }
    // Queueable execeute method runs asynchronous from original transaction
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        List<User> Updatedusers = new List<User>();
        for(UserIdVariables value : values){
            for(User use : value.users){
                use.isActive = value.newIsActive;
                Updatedusers.add(use);
            }
        }
        update Updatedusers;
    }
    @InvocableMethod(label='Update Records')
    public static void updateUsers(List<UserIdVariables> oldValues){
        UserIdVariablesClass job = new UserIdVariablesClass(oldValues);
        System.enqueueJob(job);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would love to add a pause element but its a record triggered flow so pause element isn't available in those. So adding in the queueable piece is all that is needed to get this working techincally?

Comment: @CoryIler yes, the code I wrote should work verbatim. Make sure you test it in a Sandbox if you have one though.

Comment: I attempted to create the class on this one and it gave me the below error. Not too sure what it means though.   Compile Error: InvocableMethod methods do not support parameter type of List<UserIdVariables> at line 19 column 24

Comment: @CoryIler Make sure you have the UserIdVariables declared correctly. Let me edit that in real quick.